# How does a function writer call the getByName . function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

**books-controllers**

I want the data to appear by the name in the postman and not the ID because I have information and I want to fetch it through the name in the database

```js
const getByName = async (req, res, next) => {
    const name = req.params.name;
    let book;
    try {
        book = await Book.getByName("name");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    if (!book)

        return res.status(404).json({ message: "No book found" });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ book });
};
```

**modelSchema**

Here is the Skyma model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bookSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    avilable: {
        type: Boolean,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

There in no in-built method in mongoose `getByName`. You can use generic [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) to search for object using `name`

```
let book = await Book.find({ name: name }).exec();
```

You can also use [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
async function getByName(req, res){ 
   const bookname = req.params.name ;
   try {
      const book = await Book.findOne({name: bookname})
      if(book!==null) {
        res.status(200).send({'data': book}) ;
      }
      else {
        res.status(404).send("No book found !")
      }
   }
   catch(error) {
     console.log(error)
     res.send("Error")
   }
}
```